How are transitive dependencies handled in Android libraries like core-ktx?
I was working on an Android project and realized that I could use functionality from the core-ktx library without explicitly including it in the project's dependencies. This made me question the visibility and accessibility of Gradle-passed dependencies in Android development.

For example: A->B->C
In my opinion, if library B declares a dependency on library C using the api keyword, then C is visible to any project A that depends on B.
On the contrary, if B declares C using an implementation, then C is only available at runtime and is not visible during compile time in A.

Going back to the core-ktx related question above, does this mean that one of the libraries I depend on is declaring core-ktx by way of api, otherwise I shouldn't be able to use the relevant functionality in the core-ktx library?
Also, I'm curious how this affects other dependencies.
For example: does material declare the cardview, recyclerview and constrainlayout libraries using the api, and if so, does this mean that if I reference material, I can not reference the cardview, recyclerview and constrainlayout libraries, thus minimizing the number of dependencies. libraries to minimize redundancy?


You are right about the meaning of api and implementation keyword. Your question looks not specific enough, though, so I doubt you will get an answer. It is a broad subject, and also, subject to opinion (see this discussion on Gradle forum for example).
